# How to create subplots using a for loop on different dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I've made the function "correlationCalculator" which is intended to visualize the correlation between two variables at 36 different locations.

```
def correlationCalculator(location):
   df_testLocation = getLocationDF(location, '2019-01-1', '2020-01-1')

   plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
   plt.scatter(df_testLocation['gem_intensiteit'], df_testLocation['gem_snelheid'], s = 0.5)

   z = np.polyfit(df_testLocation['gem_intensiteit'], df_testLocation['gem_snelheid'], 1)
   p = np.poly1d(z)
   plt.plot(df_testLocation['gem_intensiteit'],p(df_testLocation['gem_intensiteit']),"r--")
   plt.title(location)
   plt.xlabel('intensity')
   plt.ylabel('average speed')
   plt.show()

location_list = df_data['id_meetlocatie'].unique()
for i in location_list:
    correlationCalculator(i)
```

When I run the code, my plots come out separately like this:

[image]

However, I want all these 36 different locations to be one picture that looks somewhat like this:

[image]

Is there a way to add these plots to a subplot and then plot it like this using a for-loop that generates these different plots?

Comment: The generation and positioning of subplots is well explained in the [matplotlib tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html). How to deal with many subplots is [demonstrated here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/markevery_demo.html?highlight=markevery%20demo).  Or do you have a specific question about its implementation?

Comment: Thx for the link, helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work

```
def correlationCalculator(location, ax, j):
df_testLocation = getLocationDF(location, '2019-01-1', '2020-01-1')

ax[j].scatter(df_testLocation['gem_intensiteit'], df_testLocation['gem_snelheid'], s = 0.5)

z = np.polyfit(df_testLocation['gem_intensiteit'], df_testLocation['gem_snelheid'], 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
ax[j].plot(df_testLocation['gem_intensiteit'],p(df_testLocation['gem_intensiteit']),"r--")
ax[j].set_title(location)
ax[j].set(xlabel='intensity', ylabel ='average speed')


location_list = df_data['id_meetlocatie'].unique()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=9, ncols=4, figsize =(20,45))
fig.suptitle('Vertically stacked subplots')
j = 0
for i in location_list:
    axes = axes.flatten()
    correlationCalculator(i, axes, j)
    j+=1
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Well done! Looks great :)